# Which blogs and IoT communities might be interested in this site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As suggested in [A Recipe to Promote your Site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/), we need to start taking small, focused steps to start getting the word out about Internet of Things Stack Exchange.

To help the site to grow, I think we should try to reach out to other IoT communities and see if they're interested in writing about us or allowing us to share a link to the site. I shared a link on Reddit recently, which seemed to have a dramatic effect on the [site traffic](https://www.quantcast.com/iot.stackexchange.com#/trafficCard) (I shared the link on the the 12th of December).

Are there any sites you frequent that might be interested in discussing the site or allowing us to share our Internet of Things Stack Exchange with their community? Once we've collected a list of sites that might be interested, we should ask them if they are happy with the idea once we reach public beta, and spread the word from there.

Comment: I've already drawn over one or two from AskUbuntu... Probably the most notable is Videonauth, who qualifies as an avid user.

Comment: I have shared the first link on LinkedIn on 17th of December, seems to be that there was an increase after all.

Comment: The SmartThings community http://community.smartthings.com would be receptive. We had previously looked at doing tagged topics on the normal SE.

Comment: @JodyAlbritton thanks a lot for the suggestion! When we reach public beta, I'll try to share a link there (unless you want to do it!), since sharing while we're in private beta seems to be a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) (as per comments, I've drawn a couple over from there)
- [Internet of Things Community, IEEE](https://www.ieee.org/membership-catalog/productdetail/showProductDetailPage.html?product=CMYIOT736)
- [SAP Internet of Things Community](http://www.sap.com/community/topic/internet-of-things.html)
- [Element 14 Internet of Things](https://www.element14.com/community/groups/internet-of-things)
- [IBM Internet of Things Community](https://www-03.ibm.com/press/us/en/pressrelease/47399.wss)